# XLSX files get corrupt after downloading from Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I upload an Excel file in Xlsx format to my Data Lake Storage Gen1 folder.
When I download the same file from the Data Lake Storage the file size almost gets doubled (eg. if uploaded file was 9 kb it becomes 14 kb ) after download.
Further the downloaded file does not open and I get a message that the file is corrupt.
This problem is only seen for xlsx files. I tried with txt and csv files and did not find this problem.
Please suggest the right approach for overcoming this problem.

Regards,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed today problems downloading files from Azure Datalake Store in Azure Portal. I have not had similar problems before, but I do not frequently use the Data Explorer in Portal.

I tried downloading binary gzipped files, Excel xlsx-files and text files. Some of the text files were not corrupted, all the binary files were corrupted. The file size in ADLS does not match with downloaded file size. If the text file contains non-ASCII characters, they are corrupted and the length of the file is not correct.

Azure services can access the data correctly so to me it seems the file in ADLS is not corrupted. It seems to be a problem in download functionality in Portal. You can use the az CLI to download the files successfully:

```
az dls fs download --account yourdatalakename --source-path path/to/your/excel/file.xlsx --destination-path file.xlsx
```